# Custom Shape Label

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I'm trying to create a custom shape which is basically just an image and a shape. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to create the label for it. I want the usual Double Click to edit the shape's text but when I do that it doesn't seem to bring up the label edit.

Do I need to add a separate label object or can I just use the default label provided with the sub-shapes (the box or image)?

Answer (score 0):

As you talk of sub-shapes then I assume you have grouped the two shapes. You need to set the group behaviour (on the Developer tab) to how shapes are selected and the double-click action. Shapes don't have a label, but they do have text, there is text for the sub-shapes as well as for the group shape. You need to ensure that the group shape text is edited